# Return rows where first character is alpha and equivalent to accented characters

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a query that will return the rows where the first alpha character of the name starts with a letter given in a variable. It should also include the equivalent for non accented characters.

table in mySQL as an example:

```
id    name
--------------------------
25    Como yo te quiero
57    Me quieres
34    Ahora
45    África
568   No me mires
78    ¿A que?
89    Y sin embargo
5     ¡... A que no!
34    ...A la madre
85    Por que
51    A mi manera
```

PHP file:

```
// alpha letter to search in the name
$char = $_GET['char'];

// layout of the query
$sql = 'SELECT song_id, name FROM song WHERE song.name starts with ?';

$conn = connect('read');
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $char);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($songid, $name);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

if $char equals 'a', then the result set should returns all rows where the first alpha letter in the name starts with **a** or **A** or **á** or **Á** etc...

output:

```
34    Ahora
45    África
78    ¿A que?
5     ¡... A que no!
34    ...A la madre
51    A mi manera
```

if $char equals 'e', then the result set should returns all rows where the first alpha letter in the name starts with **e** or **E** or **é** or **É** etc...

if $char equals 'p', then the result set should returns all rows where the first alpha letter in the name starts with **p**

and so on...

What is the query ? Do i need some sort of a conversation table to tell PHP what characters are equivalent to a, e , o, etc...?

Comment: _"first non-alpha character of the name"_ => You seem to mean the first **alpha** character, not the first **non-alpha**.

Comment: @Wrikken sorry, it's a typo.. edited and fixed

Comment: I think you're going to need an array character map (`'a' => array('a','A','á','Á')...`) for an `IN()` clause, testing a `SUBSTRING()` call of the field in some way...

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: a simple `LIKE` with a correct collation takes care of the diacritics (`'a' LIKE 'Á' = true), the only problem is to find the first alpha.

Comment: @Wrikken Yea, the `etc...` worried me as to whether LIKE would take care of everything, but you're right it certainly should

Comment: Not a work around I've personally used, but you might make use of a regex replace UDF

Comment: or, i could have another column in the table with the name sanitized... stripped of all the accented characters, non alpha characters, etc. Wich will come handy when it's time to order by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query works in my test scenario:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `test` WHERE `name` REGEXP '^[^\x00-\x7F]*a'
```

Or create an array such as:

```
$replacements = array(
    'a' => array('a','Á')
    ,'b'...//etc
);
```

And then use `implode('|',$replacements[$char])` to create a statement like:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `test` WHERE `name` REGEXP '^[^\x00-\x7F]*(a|Á)'
```

`^[^\x00-\x7F]*` is looking for any non-ASCII characters at the beginning (then the a)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39516/2/0)

Comment: I appreciate the help. Tried this solution but the name 'África' is not included and it should

Comment: @Marco If you didn't want to go down the route of having a cleansed column, my updated answer has an alternative combining my original answer and what i mentioned in the comments.